# Issue assigning a value for each character of input and display the value for input

Tags: java, string, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I'm trying to create a program that accepts user input, scans each substring and checks if that character matches a position in the alphabet and if it does I want to get the equivalent position in the score String to get the score for that character and display the score for each character and the overall total.

What I have in my code below should have completed each part of what I'm trying to do, but there's a problem with the second for loop which I cannot find the solution for, I think it may be with the substrings inside the loops but I'm not sure.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class testt
{
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException
    {
        String alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        String score = "13321424185131139111144849";
        String result = "";
        int value = 0, total = 0;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter word: ");
        String input = in.nextLine();
        if(input == null || input.length() == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter input.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        String inputLower = input.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "").toLowerCase();
        String inputArray[] = inputLower.split("\\s+");
        for(int i = 0; i < alpha.length(); i++)
            if(inputLower.substring(i, i + 1) == alpha.substring(i, i + 1))
            {
                value = Integer.parseInt(score.substring(i, i + 1));
                if(value == 9)
                    value++;
                result += inputLower.substring(i, i + 1) + " will give you " + value + " point(s)\n";
                total += value;
            }
            else if(i == alpha.length() + 1)
            {
                System.out.println(result + "This word will earn you: " + total);
                System.exit(0);
            }

    }
}
```

Any advice or tips I would really appreciate since I think I have the program mostly finished.

Here's  question that I'm studying from https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlzLm.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Your actual code shows main problems from which I will state that:

1. You are looping throught `alpha.length` and you are risking to get
   into a [StringIndexOutOfBoundsException](http://scn.sap.com/message/14484954#14484954) so better check if `i`
   isn't greater than `input.length`.
2. You are using `substring(i,i+1)` to get a character at the position
   i which you can replace with `.charAt(i)` which is designed for this.
3. You are exiting the application if a character in agiven word
   doesn't match its correspending one in alpha so you are quiting
   without checking all the characters of the input...

I tried to correct your code and here's the result I came up with:

```
    String alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    String score = "13321424185131139111144849";
    String result = "";
    int value = 0, total = 0;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter word: ");
    String input = in.next();


    for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {

    if( i<alpha.length()) {
        if(input.charAt(i) == alpha.charAt(i))
        {
            value = Integer.parseInt(score.charAt(i)+"");
            if(value == 9)
                value++;
            result += input.charAt(i) + " will give you " + value + " point(s)\n";
            total += value;
        }
    }
    }
    System.out.println(result + "This word will earn you: " + total);
```

And here's a [**Live DEMO**](https://ideone.com/hkOPsc) with  `alcme` as input and gives this result:

```
a will give you 1 point(s)
c will give you 3 point(s)
e will give you 1 point(s)
This word will earn you: 5
```

Comment: Nicely done on pointing out his mistakes. I merely rewrote some of his code which is much less helpful

Answer (score 0):

Since you may have multiple words in `inputArray`, you need two nested loops instead of a single loop. The loop should walk `inputArray` one by one, then inside of that array it should walk the letters of the alphabet and do the scoring:

```
String alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
//             a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q  r s t u v w x y z
int[] score = {1,3,3,2,1,4,2,4,1,8,5,1,3,1,1,3,10,1,1,1,1,4,4,8,4,10};
int total = 0;
for (String word : inputArray) {
     int wordTotal = 0;
     for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
         char letter = word.charAt(i);
         int pos = alhpa.indexOf(letter);
         int value = score[pos];
         System.out.println("Letter "+letter+" will earn you: " + value);
         // Increment wordTotal, not total
         wordTotal += value;
     }
     System.out.println("Word "+word+" will earn you: " + wordTotal);
     total += wordTotal;
}
System.out.println("Total for all words: " + total);
```

Here are a few implementation notes:

- Using an array of integers instead of an array of characters would let you avoid "encoding" ten as `'9'`, and help you drop the `if (value == 9)` hack.
- Rather than using substrings and looking up words in a string, use `indexOf` for the `char`, and use that index to look up into the array of scores.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents I suppose, I was abit late.
You could put the actual score code into a function and call it in your loop

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    int total = 0;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter word: ");

    String input = in.nextLine();

    // Close the input stream to avoid memory leaks
    in.close();

    if (input == null || input.length() == 0) {
        System.out.println("Enter input.");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    String inputLower = input.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "").toLowerCase();

    String inputArray[] = inputLower.split("\\s+");

    // Loop through each entered word, I only did this step because you appeared to split up the input even though the Array wasn't actually being used in your original program
    for(String word : inputArray) {

        int currentWordTotal = 0;

        // Use a method to get the value for each letter in the current word
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {

            currentWordTotal += letterScore(word.charAt(i));

        }

        // Print out the word total
        System.out.println("Word: " + word + ",  will earn you: " + currentWordTotal + " points.");

        // Keep track of all word total in the event that multiple words were entered
        total += currentWordTotal;

    }

    // Print out the total for all words
    System.out.println("Your Total for the entered Words: " + total);


}

private static int letterScore(char letter) {

    char[] letters =  {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't','u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
    int[] scores = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 9, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8 ,4 ,10};

    // Here we look through the array of letters, when we find a match we use the index of the character array to get the corresponding value from the score array
    for(int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {

        if(letters[i] == letter) {
            return scores[i];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
}
```